# Command Line Argument Truncated by CreateprocessW

Tags: c++, process, command, arguments, truncate

VS10, MBCS, Unicode preprocessor defs.
Having gone through Dr Google's casebook, the best help was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053241/windows-api-createprocess-path-with-space?lq=1), but it doesn't quite address this particular problem. Consider this code where thisexePath is the path to the executable:

```
cmdLineArg = (wchar_t *)calloc(BIGGERTHANMAXPATH, sizeof(wchar_t));
wcscpy_s (cmdLineArg, maxPathFolder, L"\\\\??\\C:\\My directory\\My directory\\");
CreateProcessW (thisexePath, cmdLineArg, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &lpStartupInfo, &lpProcessInfo)
```

When the program is called

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
wchar_t hrtext[256];
swprintf_s(hrtext, sizeof(hrtext), L"%ls", lpCmdLine);
//deal with possible buffer overflow later
MessageBoxW(NULL, hrtext, L"Display", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

hrtext only displays "My directory\My directory\" Something obvious missed here?

Comment: `swprintf_s(hrtext, sizeof(hrtext), L"%ls", lpCmdLine);`   That second parameter seems wrong.  It's supposed to denote the number of characters, not number of bytes.

Comment: What did you expect to be displayed?  I see nothing in your post that suggests something else other than "My directory\My directory\" should be displayed.

Comment: What happened to the `\\\\??\\C:\\`?. Does it get automatically chopped off or something?

Comment: `"\\\\??\\"` is not a valid prefix. This should be `"\\\\?\\"` instead, with a single question mark (see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx)).

Comment: @IInspectable: Have been using it with good results in own code (mostly). Got it from an ancient OSR thread. The question has also been raised [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/348683-cant-anyone-tell-me-what-means-path-name.html)- it looks like it has something to do with symlinks for [DOSDeviceNames](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/235128)

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

```
wchar_t hrtext[256];
swprintf_s(hrtext, sizeof(hrtext), L"%ls", lpCmdLine);
```

The second parameter should denote the number of characters, not bytes.

[MSDN link to swprintf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx)

It should be this:

```
wchar_t hrtext[256];
swprintf_s(hrtext, sizeof(hrtext) / sizeof(wchar_t), L"%ls", lpCmdLine);
```

or simply:

```
wchar_t hrtext[256];
swprintf_s(hrtext, 256, L"%ls", lpCmdLine);
```

Comment: Thanks and edited the code. But the truncation still occurs!